# Why is stackoverflow not using captcha?

Tags: discussion, captcha

A site as big as stackoverflow must certainly attract a lot of spammers and bots. Hence, I find it strange that they are not using captcha, either to create a new account or to post a new answer as a guest.

Are they using hidden techniques like honeypot or they just expect the community to flag all the spams and delete it?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/captcha) is a Stack Overflow captcha. [Here](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/captcha) is a captcha on this very site.

Comment: Related: CAPTCHA frequency [is reduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53575/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing-for-5k-users) for users who are established/have recently completed a CAPTCHA.

Comment: The easiest to see that SE uses captcha is to go to [data.se] and run the query as anonymous user (without logging in)

Comment: I find it strange that people still expect to see CAPTCHA everywhere. Do you still believe CAPTCHA actually does what you think it does?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As stated by [Jeff Atwood himself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2768/284468), StackExchange uses several techniques to reduce spam.

> - captcha
> - script detection heuristics and "honeypots"
> - user flagging (spam / offensive / moderator attention)
> - auto-removal of some items based on certain flag thresholds being met
> - active moderator participation throughout the day to look at moderator flagged items

They are also using [captchas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293/284468), which are triggered under some specific conditions. I have to complete one from time to time.

Comment: 1 of the conditions of the chapcha is the time it takes between the loading of the page, and the submit of the answer

Answer (score 9):

I just got a CAPTCHA today on stackoverflow while posting an answer, with a message "Please don't take it personally" and an image of 2 humans dressed as robots.

I don't know since when have they started using CAPTCHA, but today was my first instance of using it on Stackoverflow, and I can confirm that it is being used.

Comment: Interesting, never seen one here until now.

Comment: Those are not just any two humans https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords specifically their song https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IPAOxrH7Ro

Comment: Since a very long time, but with high rep you need to post *really* fast to trigger it.

Comment: I saw this years ago

Comment: Robots behind SO noticed that you're posting robots and thought you could be one of them. Too bad you failed test by passing CAPTCHA.